# Lines not displaying in QCView, but are shown in Quartz Composer Viewer

Tags: objective-c, quartz-composer

I have a Quartz composition that draws lines using Kineme GL Line objects.  My client complained about aliasing effects, so I replaced all the Kineme GL Lines with regular Line objects.  I see a lot of improvement with respect to aliasing when I press "View" in Quartz Composer, and everything looks good.  However, in my Obj-C application, these lines are not drawn in the QCView, no matter what.  Is there something needed that I'm missing in order to enable these lines to be displayed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you install http://kineme.net/AlphaBlendMode, you can then set the `Kineme GL Line` patches to the `Alpha` blendmode, which renders beautiful antialiased lines.

Comment: I'm sorry, I did what you said but I see no difference, is there something else I need to do to see the result?

Comment: Actually, after adjusting the line width, I do see some improvement, so for that I thank you...  but I'm still confused how something can show up in the Viewer but not in a QCView.  Can anyone explain this?

Comment: That sounds like an internal framework bug.  Unfortunately, since those are opaque, there's not much we can do about it.  And, given that Apple hasn't done much with Quartz Composer in the last few years, I don't expect that reporting the bug to Apple would result it being fixed.

Comment: thanks smokris!  My issue ends up not being with rendering the lines in my QCView, I have a print button which takes a snapshot (NSImage), puts it in a new NSView, and prints.  These snapshots look awful, it seems all the effort to get rid of aliasing goes away when I take the snapshot...  is there any better way to do either do a snapshot that looks as good as what I see in my QCView, or to avoid taking a snapshot altogether?  I just care about printing.

Comment: I will put this in a new question.